# How to save a midi dataURI to the server (coldfusion or php)

Tags: php, coldfusion, midi, data-uri

I have a dataURI that when used as the href of link tag saves beautifully as a midi file when clicked on in Chrome, and after save plays fine (see code)... my question is if I sent that string to the server how can I save it as a file that plays?  I tried urldecoding and base64 encoding, but the file saved cannot play... if you could provide code in php or coldfusion that saves the string to a plauyable file that would be great!

```
    <a href="data:audio/midi,MThd%00%00%00%06%00%01%00%02%01%e0MTrk%00%00%00%1a%00%C0%02%00%FF%51%03%05%16%15%00%FF%03%08%43%6f%6f%6c%65%79%27%73%00%FF%2F%00MTrk%00%00%06%5e%00%C0%02%00%90%3e%40%83%51%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%48%40%1e%48%00%00%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%43%40%81%61%43%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%3e%40%83%51%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%48%40%1e%48%00%00%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%43%40%81%61%43%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%00%FF%2F%00">Download Midi File</a>
```

Comment: why is this urlencoded rather than base64 encoded to begin with?

Comment: "I tried urldecoding and base64 encoding, but the file saved cannot play" Because you should be passing it base64 encoded, base64 decoding, then saving.

Comment: The code is the output of a great library called abcjs, which produces midi files and clearly it works for saving the file to disk (at least in Chrome) ... my question is what do I need to do either in javascript when sending over the string or on the server to be able to accomplish what the browser does when you click on the link (save to disk)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $b64_href is your string. This code works for images.

```
if ($b64_href > 2) // to avoid substr error
{
    // DELETE "data:audio/midi," from your string
    $b64_sub = substr($b64_href, strpos($b64_href, ",") + 1);
    // CLEANUP replace space by plus
    $b64_clean = str_replace(' ', '+', $b64_sub);
    // DECODE your string
    $raw = base64_decode($b64_clean, true);
    if ($raw != FLASE)
        // SAVE
    else
        // HANDLE ERROR
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't believe it is base 64 encoded... I believe it were then it would look like data:audio/midi;base64.....  but it doesn't have the ";;base64"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... hope this helps somebody

```
<cfset dataURI="data:audio/midi,MThd%00%00%00%06%00%01%00%03%01%e0MTrk%00%00%00%1a%00%C0%02%00%FF%51%03%05%16%15%00%FF%03%08%43%6f%6f%6c%65%79%27%73%00%FF%2F%00MTrk%00%00%06%5e%00%C0%02%00%90%3e%40%83%51%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%48%40%1e%48%00%00%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%43%40%81%61%43%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%3e%40%83%51%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%48%40%1e%48%00%00%47%40%81%43%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%43%40%81%61%43%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%83%51%40%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%45%40%83%51%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%47%40%83%51%47%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4f%40%81%61%4f%00%0f%51%40%81%61%51%00%0f%4e%40%81%61%4e%00%0f%4c%40%81%61%4c%00%0f%49%40%81%61%49%00%0f%4a%40%81%61%4a%00%0f%47%40%81%61%47%00%0f%45%40%81%61%45%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%81%61%40%00%0f%42%40%81%61%42%00%0f%3e%40%81%61%3e%00%0f%40%40%87%31%40%00%00%FF%2F%00MTrk%00%00%07%0b%00%C0%02%00%C0%02%83%60%90%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%26%40%81%70%26%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%21%40%81%70%21%00%81%70%32%30%00%36%30%00%39%30%81%70%32%00%00%36%00%00%39%00%81%70%28%40%81%70%28%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%81%70%23%40%81%70%23%00%81%70%34%30%00%37%30%00%3b%30%81%70%34%00%00%37%00%00%3b%00%00%FF%2F%00">

<!--- strip out the MIME type info (the text before the first comma)  --->
<cfset dataURI =listLast(dataURI)>

<!-- get rid of %... is this used as a separator for human readability? --->
<cfset dataURI =replace(dataURI,"%","","all")>

<!--- change MThd to hex --->
<cfset dataURI =replace(dataURI,"MThd","4D546864","all")>

<!--- change MTrk to hex --->
<cfset dataURI =replace(dataURI,"MTrk","4D54726B","all")>

<!--- uppercase --->
<cfset dataURI =Ucase(dataURI)>

<!--- convert to binary encoded as hex--->
<cfset dataURI = BinaryDecode(dataURI, "Hex")>

<cffile action="write" file = "#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#myConvertedFile.midi" output="#dataURI#" addNewLine = "no" >
```